# Magento check configurable item quntity using custom script

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, cart, api, model

I have created soap api file.When user will update the quntity in cart then it will send request to myfile.  In myfile i have set the code to check the requested quntity by user is available or not. it means if only 2 quntity left and quntity entered by user is 10  then it will throw error that requested quntity not available.  I have done this for simple product but how can i do that for configurable item.

**Is there any programmatic way i can check requested configurable product quntity available or not?**

```
      $json_request = '{"jsonrequest" : {"cartitems" : [ {"product_id" :"533","custom_option_id" : [{"value_id" :"53","option_id" :"92"} ],"type" :"configurable","qty" :"10"}],  "totalitems":"1"}}';
    $json_request = json_decode($json_request);

     if ($json_request)
     {
      foreach($json_request as $key => $jv)
      {

      // code...

         $itemcount = count($jv->cartitems);
         if ($itemcount)
           {

           // for($i=1;$i<=$itemcount;$i++){

           foreach($jv->cartitems as $key => $pv)
                {
                $pid = $pv->product_id;
                $pqty = $pv->qty;
                $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);

                // print_r($_product->getData());

                if ($_product->getTypeId() == 'configurable')
                     {


                     $childIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
                     foreach($pv->custom_option_id as $key => $ov)
                          {
                          $simple_collection = $childIds->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('color', $ov->value_id)->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
                          foreach($simple_collection as $key => $smvalue)
                               {

                               // code...

                               $stocklevel = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($smvalue->getId())->getQty();
                               if ($stocklevel < $pqty)
                                    {
                                    $qtymsg = $smvalue->getName() . "'s only " . $stocklevel . " quntity available";

                                    // echo $qtymsg;

                                    break;
                                    }
                               }
                          }
                     }

                // echo "te";
                // break;

                }
             }
         }
      }

   if ($qtymsg)
   {
   $data = array(
       "message" => $qtymsg
   );
   $status = 'fail';
   $final_array = array(
      "result" => $data,
        "status" => $status
     );
    }
  else
   {
    $cartarray = $json_request->jsonrequest->cartitems;
    $status = 'success';
    try
      {

      // $proxy = new SoapClient(SOAP_URL1);
      //    $sessionId = $proxy->login(SOAP_USERNAME, SOAP_KEY);

      if ($cartarray)
           {
           foreach($cartarray as $prod)
                {
                $product_id = $prod->product_id;
                $item_id = $prod->item_id;
                $qty = $prod->qty;
                $type = $prod->type;
                $custom_option_id = $prod->custom_option_id;
                $arrProducts = array();
                $product = array();
                $product['product_id'] = $product_id;
                $product['qty'] = $qty;
                if ($type == 'simple')
                     {
                     if ($custom_option_id)
                          {
                          $custom_option = array();
                          foreach($custom_option_id as $option)
                               {
                               $custom_option[$option->option_id] = $option->value_id;
                               }

                          $product['options'] = $custom_option;
                          }
                     }

                if ($type == "configurable")
                     {
                     if ($custom_option_id)
                          {
                          $custom_option = array();
                          foreach($custom_option_id as $option)
                               {
                               $custom_option[$option->option_id] = $option->value_id;
                               }

                          $product['super_attribute'] = $custom_option;
                          }
                     }

                if ($type != "giftcards")
                     {
                     $arrProducts = array(
                          $product
                     );

                     // $resultCartProductUpdate = $proxy->call($sessionId,"cart_product.update",
                     // array($shoppingcartid,$arrProducts));

                     $resultCartProductUpdate = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart_product_api')->update($shoppingcartid, $arrProducts);
                     }
                  else
                     {
                     $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
                     $write->update("sales_flat_quote_item", array(
                          "qty" => $qty
                     ) , "item_id=$item_id");
                     $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($shoppingcartid);
                     $quote->collectTotals()->save();

                     // echo $item_id;

                     }
                }

           $msg = 'Product was updated to your shopping cart.';
           }
        else
           {
           $msg = 'Please pass valid options.';
           $status = 'fail';
           }
      }

    catch(Exception $e)
      {
      $msg = $e->getMessage();
      $status = 'fail';
      }

    $cartdata = array(
      "shoppingcartid" => $shoppingcartid
    );
    $data = array(
      "message" => $msg,
         "data" => $cartdata
    );
   $final_array = array(
      "result" => $data,
      "status" => $status
     );
   }

  $final_array = json_encode($final_array);
  echo convert($final_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This functionality already provided in default Magento.

[image]